are standard Audio CDs (CDDA) supported by the linux kernel?
For purposes of reading the contents both music and metadata, does the Linux Kernel support CDDA (standard commercial audio "compact disc digital audio" or does the support come from secondary tools and software

AFAIK the kernel supports hardware.

Tips: cdrecord - https://linux.die.net/man/1/cdrecord, cdda2wav - https://linux.die.net/man/1/cdda2wav

I'm thinking the answer is NO, the Linux kernel doesn't support CD-DA, but GNU has available the libcdio library which includes cdparanoia tool
